# Stream Resource as REST download

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, streaming

So, I have a REST endpoint for downloading a file from my backend-for-frontend (BFF):

```
@Path("/attachments")
public interface AttachmentApi {
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({"*/*", "application/problem+json"})
    Response getAttachment(@PathParam("id") String id);
}
```

The BFF is then simply forwarding the request to another backend, downloading the file and forwarding it to the client.
That was working fine for small files, but not for bigger ones, since it ran into `DataBufferLimitException`s:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144.
```

Yes, I could simply increase the max memory in the Spring Boot config. But instead I found it more suitable to **stream instead of download** the file, especially for bigger files. So, I adjusted my implementation and came up with the following:

```
@Component
@Api
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AttachmentApiImpl implements AttachmentApi {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AttachmentApiImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Response getAttachment(String id) {
        ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> attachmentServiceResponse = findById(id);

        StreamingOutput streamingOutput = output -> {
            try (InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(attachmentServiceResponse.getBody()).getInputStream()) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException("Error streaming file", e);
            }
        };

        return Response.ok(streamingOutput)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.ETAG + ", " + HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
                .header(HttpHeaders.ETAG, attachmentServiceResponse.getHeaders().getETag())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, attachmentServiceResponse.getHeaders().getContentDisposition())
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, attachmentServiceResponse.getHeaders().getContentType())
                .build();
    }

    private ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> findById(String id) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/attachments/{id}")
                        .build(id))
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(InputStreamResource.class)
                .block();
    }
}
```

But that didn't really change anything. I still get the `DataBufferLimitException` and it seems like it is not really streaming as intended. I also read something about using `DataBuffer` and `DataBufferUtils`, but I am not really sure how to use that.

Does someone has an idea, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are blocking the reactive part, which will lead to it being totally read into a buffer and placed into an inputstream. So you are still reading everything. Ditch the `WebClient` (or use it properly) and open a `UrlConnection` yourself and pipe the inputstream directly into the outputstream.

Comment: spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 10MB

Comment: @M.Deinum Sounds promising. I like to stay with `WebClient` for now, if it is possible. Can you please give me an example on how to "use it properly"?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you are trying to bridge the reactive and blocking world with an `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. This will not work and how you are currently doing it will retrieve everything into a `byte[]` and wrap that with an `InputStream`.

If you want streaming you will need to use a `DataBuffer` and copy the read data to the `OutputStream`. You shouldn't block anywhere and only `subscribe` to the mono in the end.

```java
private Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>> findById(String id) {
  return webClient.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
          .path("/attachments/{id}")
          .build(id))
       .retrieve()
       .toEntityFlux(DataBuffer.class);
}
```

Now you get a 1 or more `DatBuffer` which you can write directly to the `OutputStream` using the `DataBufferUtils`.

```java
    @Override
    public Response getAttachment(String id) {
        Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>> attachmentServiceResponse = findById(id);

        StreamingOutput streamingOutput = output -> {
           attachmentServiceResponse.map( (res) -> DataBufferUtils.write(res.getBody(), output)).subscribe();
        };

        return Response.ok(streamingOutput);
}
```

Drawback no easy way to copy the headers. If you would have used Spring Webflux (or Spring MVC) as your web technology you could just return the `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>` from the method and Spring would handle everything for you.